# What is the Python syntax for adding the reduce part of a map/reduce pair in the ViewDefinition method of couchdb?

Tags: python, couchdb

I would like to add a permanent view to my couchdb database using the ViewDefinition class in Python rather than use Futon to define the view.

I have successfully added the map part of the map/reduce pair like so:

```
postbyid = ViewDefinition(‘application’,‘postbyid’, ‘function(doc) {if (doc.type==”posts”) {emit(doc.id, doc)};}’)

postbyid.sync(database)
```

But I cannot work out the syntax for adding the reduce part of the map/reduce pair.

For instance, if my intended view looks like (copied from Futon):

```
"views": {
   "postbyid": {
       "map": "function(doc) {\n\tif (doc.type==\"post\") {\n  emit(doc.id, doc)};\n}",
       "reduce": "_count"
```

How do I code the reduce part of the map/reduce pair in the ViewDefinition class?

Alternatively, am I on the right track or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think I might have answered my own question - The reduce function is the fourth parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduce function is entered as the fourth parameter.  I found this by looking through the couchdb library code as the documentation and examples are a little sparse.

```
postbyid = ViewDefinition(‘application’,‘postbyid’, ‘function(doc) {if (doc.type==”posts”) {emit(doc.id, doc)};}’ , '_count')
```

Hope this helps somebody else.